# IRAF for Mac m1

Tags: anaconda, conda, iraf

Hi I'm trying to install IRAF with anaconda I follow these steps, but when I run iras, and I want to make something, this program doesn't recognize the commands of IRAF
i follow this tutorial: https://astroconda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Astroconda IRAF is a 32-bit version and does not work on M1 Macs, since they are not able to run 32-bit code.
To install IRAF for an M1 Mac, you should compile it manually, as described in https://iraf-community.github.io/install. This installs the latest 64-bit IRAF version. PyRAF (for Python 3) can then simply installed with **pip3**, see https://iraf-community.github.io/pyraf.html.

However, it is not recommended to start with IRAF unless there is a real need for it. IRAF is old software with an uncertain future and no institutional support. The Astropy Python package and its ecosystem provide good alternatives for many tasks of IRAF. https://astropy.org